# Need to add the new Google Maps API KEY to my existing Drupal7 site

Tags: javascript, google-maps, drupal-7

In my drupal site i am getting the error alert like **"This page can't load Google Maps correctly."**. My website is built on drupal7. Where to add the script tag with that new API key generated through admin login UI. I mean in which module of UI i has to change. Please find the attached screenshot for reference.
Any quick help more helpful.
[image]

Comment: As per FAQs 
Can I still use Google Maps Platform for free?
Yes. When you enable billing, you get $200 free usage every month for Maps, Routes, or Places. Based on the millions of users using our APIs today, most of them can continue to use Google Maps Platform for free with this credit.
How to use this?Generated an API key and added that script in html page but it doesn't work.

Comment: I have a client who is still using old account account without credit card or limits. Were existing users allowed to continue with old terms of usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get a license for google maps api as , Google has implemented a new Pricing module in july for google maps.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key
Through this process if we generate key and add script with API key to application doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Google's new billing and pricing model requires you to add a credit card to use even the free API's. If you are using the Javascript API for Static Maps, it is no longer free. The documentation/tutorial page which shows code examples, will provide a key, however it will not work until you add your billing info.

https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Comment: So as per your comment we need to add the billing details even for free. If we crossed the free usage it will detect from account. Is it right?